# Android layout webview between another two views

Tags: android, android-layout, webview

What's the best approach to have a layout with the following:

---

Spinner (default height)

WebView (all the space between the two views (Spinner and Button))

Button (default height)

---

How is it possible to specify the height of the WebView to take all the space between the two (i.e. if they are resized later, the WebView will automatically be adjusted).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `RelativeLayout` as the parent layout. Align the Spinner to the top of the parent. Align the Button to the bottom of the parent. For the WebView, set the height as match_parent and then use the `android:layout_below` and `android:layout_above` attributes to make sure that it always lies between the two views.

(I would've given the code but I don't want to. You might just copy paste with zero learning.)